# Log in screen not showing how many unread email. Winxp, MS Outlook 7

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, windows-registry, microsoft-outlook-2007

I want to know how many unread email message I have when I log in(i.e when my system gets boots up). But that feature is not ON?

In my registry -----------> unread mail, when I click on my email id, following details are displayed:

```
Default (Value not set)
Message count -1 (Hexa decimal).
```

My OS is win XP.  I use MS outlook 7. 
Thank you for your help...

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to show this information at logon. This feature is only for when you lock the pc.

The reason is, that windows does not load your profile before you sign in, and as such it doesn't know your login details etc. Once logged in, and locking your pc, it should show you the amount of unread emails.

It would be possible to show this if you use the hibernation function instead of shutdown, because then the profile is still loaded.